# Получение данных с Arduino на php

Tags: php, arduino, com-порт

Использую Arduino UNO. Суть в том, что Ардуинка отправляет на COM значения в диапазоне 100-1000, каждый тик через:

```
Serial.println(analogInput1);
```

Но когда принимаю их через:

```
$com = fopen("com11", "r");
$return = ord(fread($com, 9600));
fclose($com);
```

у меня всегда на выходе 2.

В чём проблема может быть?

Comment: Например в том, что вы порт не настраиваете

Comment: Можно по подробнее, что вы имеет ввиду?

Comment: Я имею в виду настройку порта: скорость, число бит данных, стопов, четность и так далее.

Comment: Ещё бы разобраться где указать подобные параметры

Comment: Гуглите и нагуглится вам. Но PHP для таких целей - точно плохой выбор.

Comment: Я знаю, плохой, но очень нужно)